# How does youtube encode their urls?

Tags: php, url, encryption, youtube

Quick Question

How does youtube encode theirs urls? take below

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MhWyAL2hKlk

what are they doing to get the value MhWyAL2hKlk

are they using some kind of encryption then decrypting at their end

I want to something similar with a website i am working on below looks horrible.

```
http://localhost:8888/example/account_player/?playlist=drum+and+bass+music
```

i would like to encode the urls to act like youtubes dont know how they do it tho.

Any advice

Comment: i dont think they encode anything, they just generate a random string but if you know it better tell me otherwise

Comment: Youtube isn't necessarily encoding anything. It's most likely a randomly generated string.

Comment: Its the randomly generated unique key for each video.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Just use an auto-increment ID value (from a database). Although I personally like the long URLs.

Comment: How do you know its auto-increment?

Comment: Youtube isn't using autoincremented. I'm suggesting that you do. Why is "random looking string" important? A single number is even more terse.

Comment: Thats for all the answers think i am just going to stick to ids dont know why i prefer youtubes strings just looks and feels better i suppose thanks

Answer (score 4):

Well, technically speaking, YouTube generates video IDs by using an algorithm. Honestly, I have no idea. It could be a hashsum of the entire video file + a salt using the current UNIX time, or it could be a base64 encoding of something unique to the video. But I do know that it's most likely not random, because if it were, the risk of collision would be too high.

For the sake of example, though, we'll assume that YouTube does generate random ID's. Keep in mind that when using randomly generated values to store something, it is generally a good idea to implement collision checking to ensure that a new object doesn't overwrite the existing one. In practice, though, I would recommend using a hashing algorithm, since they are one-way and very effective at preventing collisions.

So, I'm not very familiar with PHP. I had to write it in [JavaScript](https://jsfiddle.net/339Lenwz/) first. Then, I ported it to PHP, which turned out to be relatively simple:

```
function randch($charset){
    return $charset[rand() % strlen($charset)];
}

function randstr($len, $charset = "0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ_-"){
    $out = [];

    for($i = 0; $i < $len; $i++){
        array_push($out, randch($charset));
    }
    return join("", $out);
}
```

What this does is generate a random string `len` characters long via the given `charset`.

Here's some sample output:

```
randstr(5)              -> 1EWHd
randstr(30)             -> atcUVgfhAmM5bXz-3jgyRoaVnnY2jD
randstr(30, "asdfASDF") -> aFSdSAfsfSdAsSSddFFSSsdasDDaDa
```

Though it's not a good idea to use such a short charset.

```
randstr(30, "asdf")

sdadfaafsdsdfsaffsddaaafdddfad
adaaaaaafdfaadsadsdafdsfdfsadd
dfaffafaaddfdddadasaaafsfssssf

randstr(30)

r5BbvJ45HEN6dWtNZc5ZvHGLCg4Qyq
50vKb1rh66WWf9RLZQY2QrMucoNicl
Mklh3zjuRqDOnVYeEY3B0V3Moia9Dn
```

Now let's say you have told the page to use this function to generate a random id for a video that was just uploaded, now you want to store this key in a table with a link to the relevant data to display the right page. If an id is requested via `$_GET` (e.g. `/watch?v=02R0-1PWdEf`), you can tell the page to check this key against the database containing the video ids, and if it finds a match, grab the data from that key, else give a 404.

You can also encode directly to a base 64 string if you don't want it to be random. This can be done with `base64_encode()` and `base64_decode()`. For example, say you have the data for the video in one string `$str="filename=apples.avi;owner=coolpixlol124"`, for whatever reason. `base64_encode($str)` will give you `ZmlsZW5hbWU9YXBwbGVzLmF2aTtvd25lcj1jb29scGl4bG9sMTI0`.

To decode it later use `base64_decode($new_str)`, which will give back the original string.

Though, as I said before, it's probably a better idea to use a hashing algorithm like `SHA`.

I hope this helped.

EDIT: I forgot to mention, YouTube's video ids as of now are 11 characters long, so if you want to use the same kind of thing, you would want to use `randstr(11)` to generate an 11 digit random string, like this sample id I got: `6AMx8N5r6cg`

EDIT 2 (2015.12.17): Completely re-wrote answer. Original was crap, I don't know what I was thinking when I wrote it.

Comment: I just re-wrote and optimized the code. Here is the new gen function complete with a demonstration http://jsfiddle.net/MLJaB/

Comment: I know this is a very old question - but there are two '5's in your php answer above

Answer (score 2):

Your question is similar to this other SO question which contains some optimised generator functions along with a clear description of the problem you're trying to solve:

[php - help improve the efficiency of this youtube style url generator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1853471/php-help-improve-the-efficiency-of-this-youtube-style-url-generator)

It will provide you with code, a better understanding of performance issues, and a better understanding of the problem domain all at once.

Answer (score 1):

Dunno how exactly google generates their strings, but the idea is really simple. Create a table like:

```
+----------+------------------------------+
| code     | url                          |
+----------+------------------------------+
| asdlkasd | playlist=drum+and+bass+music |
+----------+------------------------------+
```

Now, create your url like:

```
http://localhost:8888/example/account_player/asdlkasd
```

After that, just read compare your own made code with the database url and load your image, video or whatever you intend to.

PS: This is just a fast example. It can be done in many other ways also of course.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use decimal numbers, you can encode them into base36:

```
echo base_convert(123456789, 10, 36); // => "21i3v9"
```

And decode back:

```
echo base_convert("21i3v9", 36, 10); // => "123456789"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function alphaID($in, $to_num = false, $pad_up = false, $pass_key = null)
{
  $out   =   '';
   $index = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ';
   $base  = strlen($index);

   if ($pass_key !== null) {

for ($n = 0; $n < strlen($index); $n++) {
  $i[] = substr($index, $n, 1);
}

$pass_hash = hash('sha256',$pass_key);
$pass_hash = (strlen($pass_hash) < strlen($index) ? hash('sha512', $pass_key) : $pass_hash);

for ($n = 0; $n < strlen($index); $n++) {
  $p[] =  substr($pass_hash, $n, 1);
}

array_multisort($p, SORT_DESC, $i);
$index = implode($i);
}

if ($to_num) {
// Digital number  <<--  alphabet letter code
$len = strlen($in) - 1;

for ($t = $len; $t >= 0; $t--) {
  $bcp = bcpow($base, $len - $t);
  $out = $out + strpos($index, substr($in, $t, 1)) * $bcp;
}

if (is_numeric($pad_up)) {
  $pad_up--;

  if ($pad_up > 0) {
    $out -= pow($base, $pad_up);
  }
}
} else {
// Digital number  -->>  alphabet letter code
if (is_numeric($pad_up)) {
  $pad_up--;

  if ($pad_up > 0) {
    $in += pow($base, $pad_up);
  }
}

for ($t = ($in != 0 ? floor(log($in, $base)) : 0); $t >= 0; $t--) {
  $bcp = bcpow($base, $t);
  $a   = floor($in / $bcp) % $base;
  $out = $out . substr($index, $a, 1);
  $in  = $in - ($a * $bcp);
}
}

return $out;
}
?>
```

you can encypt or decrypt using this function.

```
<?php

$random_id=57256;
$encode=alphaID($random_id);
$decode=alphaID($encode,true); //where boolean true reverse the string back to original

echo "Encode : {$encode} <br> Decode : {$decode}";
?>
```

Just visit the below for more info :

http://kvz.io/blog/2009/06/10/create-short-ids-with-php-like-youtube-or-tinyurl/